# Does the union of two Hausdorff subspaces Hausdorff in this case?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\{X^n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be a filtration of $X$ (i.e. $X^n\subset X^{n+1}$) whose union is $X$.

Assume that $X^{-2}=\emptyset$ and $X^0\setminus X^{-1}$ is discrete. Assume also that $X$ has the weak topology determined by $\{X^n\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$. Define $A:=X^{-1}$ and $B:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} X^n\setminus A$.

Now the question: If $A,B$ are both Hausdorff, then is $X$ Hausdorff?

Moreover, if $A,B$ are $T_4$, then is $X$  $T_4$?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For instance, $X=X^0$ could be any space with two points, with $X^{-1}$ containing only one of the points.  Then $A$ and $B$ both have only one point and so are $T_4$, but $X$ does not have to be Hausdorff.